# How to work with a team of developers and version control with svn for Apex and Lightning Components?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, versioning, sublime, version-control

We have been trying to figure out a way to work as a Team on a salesforce project using Apex and lightning components.

I envision a scenario where each developer would have his/hers own org (developer account) to develop and test against. We would all be committing to one svn repository on our server and later deploying that code to the company org.

We also would like to develop on our preferred IDEs on my case, Sublime.

We have tried force CLI migration tool, ANT and MavensMate so far to do that but we haven't been successful yet.

It's a requirement to be able to retrieve and deploy APEX and Lightning components.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here is an article I had stored in my bookmarks that may help. I had a better one but must've  deleted it. http://www.redargyle.com/blog/automated-salesforce-metadata-backup-using-jenkins-git/

Comment: I think if you created a repo, and then added the necessary files to the .gitignore this could totally be done.  I can't think of anything you would have to put in the .gitignore, but if you had issues with a file that differentiated the organization that's what I would do.

Comment: i would like to check if you got solution on this.when I went through ligthning component tutorial, we use developer console but in reallife many developer might touch the same component, how to control this ?i am not sure if using sublime is achievable especially when we  need to merge and integrate the code.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I've seen this work is having each developer maintain their own sandbox.  They can branch the svn/git repository and make changes to their branch in their own sandbox, and then have a shared sandbox which represents trunk/master branch.

git rebasing or svn updating is up to the developer, and merge conflicts are also up to the developer.

If each developer does not have their own sandbox, then there is **guaranteed** contention.

[Here's a guide on how to setup SVN with Salesforce on Sublime](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/SFDC/Setting+Up+Version+Control).

Comment: I know your answer was like 4 years back, but can you update your broken link please?